# Problem with adding objects to manytomany fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I have a User model:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    followers_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    followings_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    followings = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

And there's a view for adding/removing user objects from followers/followings:

```py
def follow(request, follow, user):
    if (request.method == 'PUT'):
        following_user = User.objects.get(username=user)
        follower_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        if follow:
            # Follow
            following_user.followers.add(follower_user)
            following_user.followers_num += 1

            follower_user.followings.add(following_user)
            follower_user.followings_num += 1
        else:
            # Unfollow
            following_user.followers.remove(follower_user)
            following_user.followers_num -= 1

            follower_user.followings.remove(following_user)
            follower_user.followings_num -= 1
        
        following_user.save()
        follower_user.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

I want it to add `follower_user` to the followers of `following_user` and add `following_user` to the followings of `follower_user`. However, instead of doing so, it adds `follower_user` not only to the followers of `following_user`, but it also adds it to the followings of `following_user`. Why does it happen?

Edit:
I added `symmetrical=False` to fields but that caused an error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
network.User.followers: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'network.User.followers' clashes with reverse accessor for 'network.User.followings'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'network.User.followers' or 'network.User.followings'.
network.User.followings: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'network.User.followings' clashes with reverse accessor for 'network.User.followers'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'network.User.followings' or 'network.User.followers'.
```

Comment: Because relations in Django to the `self` are by default symmetric.

Comment: Thanks. I added `symmetrical=False` to fields but that caused an error:

Comment: likley simply migrating will not be possible, so likely you first should remove both m2m relations, migrate, and then create a new non-symmetrical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, instead of doing so, it adds follower_user not only to the `followers` of `following_user`, but it also adds it to the `followings` of `following_user`. Why does it happen?

Because relations in Django to the `self` are by default symmetric. You should make the relation asymmetric by setting [**`symmetrical=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) and simply use *one* `ManyToManyField`, so:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name='following'
    )
```

The logic is simply:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def follow(request, follow, user):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        following_user = get_object_or_404(User, username=user)
        follower_user = request.user
        if follow:
            following_user.followers.add(follower_user)
        else:
            following_user.followers.remove(follower_user)
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

If user *A* is in the `.followers` of *B*, then *B* is automatically in the `.following` of *A*, so there is no need to use two relations.

Furthermore you do not have to keep track of the number of followers, you can count this using [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) when necessary.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Answer (score 2):

Use this as your model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    followers_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    followings_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followings', null=True, blank=True)
```

This makes use of the [symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) logic that Willem mentioned. This will avoid you having to keep track of the relationship in two ManyToManyFields.